# Remove duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please assist me in writing a query to remove duplicates. See below
looking the results I have a column added as my status (manually) added. The category is the one determining where a record is a duplicate or not. In this case our main focus is cancellation. If for a member a cancellation has reinstatement after as member Y007. is not considered as a duplicate. But if a member has more than one cancellation then is considered as a duplicate because if we were to count a number of duplicates both of them will be counted which will give incorrect results. We need to just count a member once. The cancellation can either done by a user or user1 and it is possible to have user1 done more than one cancellation. 
can you please assist me on writing a query that will ensure that no duplicates are shown. only one record for that member not 2 records both as duplication

```
CreateYear  MonthDay     Category           Member  Status
2014    July    1    Cancellation by User   Y0007   
2014    July    1    Reinstatement by User  Y0007   not duplicate
2014    July    2    Cancellation by User   Y0007   
2014    July    2    Reinstatement by User  Y0007   
2014    July    1    Cancellation by User   O0031   not duplicate
2014    July    8    Reinstatement by User  O0031   
2014    July    1    Cancellation by User   O0135   not duplicate
2014    July    8    Reinstatement by User  O0135   
2014    July    3    Cancellation by User   P0422   duplicate
2014    July    4    Cancellation by User2  P0422   
2014    July    4    Cancellation by User   E3488   not duplicate
2014    July    8    Reinstatement by  User E3488
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: am using sql server 2012

Comment: When you say 'remove' you mean to say delete the record or just simply do not include as a result of your desired query?

Comment: yes to delete, it can go both ways either to delete or exclude the duplicates

Comment: Does this table have an id column to distinguish the records or is this all of the columns?

Comment: Hi Jenn this is a temporary table that I created from a select query of which takes this information to multiple tables. I created this temporary table so I can be able to delete records I don't need to answer your question no it doesn't have unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Strategy**

In order to remove the duplicates, let's start by writing some code that only selects the duplicates. If you can write the proper select statement, it is easy to convert it into a delete statement. Now, the select statement is a little tricky because we need to compare the dates, but your dates are split into three columns and the month is not stored as a number. However, if we concatenate the three columns together and cast them as dates, we can compare the date values and find cancellations that occurred several times in a row.

**Query**

```
Select *
From testtable t
Where category = 'Cancellation'
and exists (Select 1
            From testtable t2
            Where t2.category = t.category
            and     t2.Member = t.Member
            and     Cast(t2.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t2.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t2.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date) >
                    Cast(t.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date)
            and not exists (Select 1
                            From testtable t3
                            Where t3.category = 'Reinstatement'
                            and     t3.Member = t.Member
                            and     Cast(t3.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t3.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t3.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date) >=
                                    Cast(t.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date)
                            and     Cast(t2.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t2.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t2.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date) >=
                                    Cast(t3.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t3.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t3.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date)
                            )
            )
```

**Explaination**

This query looks a little bit intense, but let's talk through it. So first we have the `select * From testtable t` all of this you are probably used to seeing, except perhaps the alias. I have named this particular instance of `testtable Where category = 'Cancellation'` t. I have essentially given it the nickname t so that instead of referring to the table by its name (and getting confused because I am using the same table three times), I can refer to it as t.

Now, the `exists`. This may or may not be different syntax than you've seen. Exists returns true if there is something in the parenthesis that follows it and returns false if there is nothing in those parenthesis. I am using this exists to check in the testtable for a different record that is newer than the cancellation that we are looking at and is also a cancellation.

This is where the date comes in. We only want know if there are other cancellations where the Month and Day is greater than the cancellation that we are looking at. For Member P0422, when we are determining if the cancellation on July 3 is a duplicate, we want to find the cancellation on July 4.

In the subselect I am using `not exists`. The last thing we need to check is if there is a Reinstatement between the two cancellations. If there is one, we want to ignore the cancellation and move on to check the next row. [See the query in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9c66/9)

**Cast as date in-depth look**

I have used syntax like `Cast(t2.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t2.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t2.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date)` several times in this query to figure out what the date of the record is. I have done this because the date of the cancellation (or reinstatement) has been broken up into three columns.

Let's look at what this is doing for the following record.

> ```
> CreateYear  MonthDay     Category           Member  Status
> 2014    July    1    Cancellation by User   Y0007
> ```

First is the concatenation. `t2.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t2.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t2.CreateYear as varchar(4))` this part grabs the different pieces of information from each of the columns and stick it all together. The year and the day were ints and not varchars, so first I switched them to be varchars. The result of this line is `July 1 2014`.

Then, we `Cast (... as date)`. Casting allows you to take a piece of information and make it into a different data type. So, this tells sql to look at `July 1 2014` as if it were a date instead of a string. All of this was done so we can compare the dates. Sql knows how to tell what date is more recent than another, which is why I converted these values. Instead of doing this, you could compare each piece of the date separately, but either way is still a lot of work.

**Let's Delete!**

Now that we found all of the rows that are duplicates, we can change the query to delete them really easily.

```
Delete t
From testtable t
Where category = 'Cancellation'
and exists (Select 1
            From testtable t2
            Where t2.category = t.category
            and     t2.Member = t.Member
            and     Cast(t2.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t2.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t2.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date) >
                    Cast(t.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date)
            and not exists (Select 1
                            From testtable t3
                            Where t3.category = 'Reinstatement'
                            and     t3.Member = t.Member
                            and     Cast(t3.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t3.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t3.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date) >=
                                    Cast(t.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date)
                            and     Cast(t2.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t2.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t2.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date) >=
                                    Cast(t3.CreateMonth + ' '+ cast(t3.CreateDay as varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(t3.CreateYear as varchar(4)) as date)
                            )
            )
```

Comment: Hi Jenn Thank you so much for your assistance, The logic you used helped me a lot I even tried this in different ways with the use of cross apply and inner joins. You explained this very well in a way that even if I encounter an error I didn't have any difficulties in solving that. Keep up the good work am all smiles now. Thank you soooo much

Comment: @user1538257 Great, I'm happy to hear it! Would you accept my answer?

Comment: @user1538257 there is a little check box next to each answer. you can show that the answer was helpful to you by 'accepting' it. Also, if there is more to the question, I would recommend asking a new question. It will be much easier to get new answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can write somthing like:-

```
 DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME 
 WHERE member NOT IN (SELECT MAX(member) FROM TABLE_NAME 
                      GROUP BY CreateYear, MonthDay, Category, Member, Status);
```

I Hope this wil solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Ankit, this wont work see I tried that few minutes ago. you must also consider that am looking at the category "cancelations" to exclude the duplicates. considering that for example member "E3488" is a duplicate due to having more than one cancellation. at the same time we also have  member "Y0007" which is not considered as a duplicate and also have more than one cancellations. so if we looking at the max of cancellation members this two will be retrieved which ie wrong becauseI only want to retrieve just one member cancellation.

Comment: well i didn't try this ever. so i was just giving you a hint to do somthing like same. But extremely sorry for not helping you so much.

Comment: its okay thanx though

Answer (score 0):

```
  ;with TempCte as (Select CreateYear,MonthDay,Category,Member, MemberCount =ROW_NUMBER()
                    over(PARTITION By CreateYear, MonthDay, Category, Member, Status Order By CreateYear)
                    From TableName)

   Delete TempCte 
   Where MemberCount >1
```

Comment: Hi humpty can you please explain the logic you used as to what each line of code does

Answer (score -1):

you can use group by

```
Select  Create,Year,MonthDay,Category , Member,Status 
From tblname  
Group By Category
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.